# API logging using log4php

Tags: php, log4php

I have log4php working via the command line successfully but I am struggling when using it with an PHP API (via Apache).

The error I am getting is;

> PHP Warning:  log4php: Configuration failed. Error loading configuration file: failed
>   to load external entity "logging.xml"

logging.xml is in the same directory as the PHP file and is loaded via;

```
$configFile = "logging.xml";
Logger::configure($configFile);
```

Ideas please? I tried changing it to use the full URL for the file and the full local path and they result in the same error.

The same setup works via the CLI.

Comment: Post your config file.

Comment: <configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/"><appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderDailyFile">
<layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
<param name="conversionPattern" value="%date{Y/m/d H:i,s} - %message%newline" />
</layout>
<param name="file" value="/var/log/scripts/webhook-%s.log" />
<param name="datePattern" value="dmY" />
</appender>
<root>
<appender_ref ref="default" />
</root>
</configuration>